# Why my comparison of two dates in PHP is not working?

Tags: php, date

I have removed the desired output and some styling as they dont affect the question. I cant seem to compare the two dates properly, idea is that if currentDate is greater than deadlineDate there will be no output for that route. What i am trying to do is prevent the system from listing routes which are already closed. I dont understand why its so difficult or then i am missing something very basic here.

```
<?php
$driveDays = mysql_query("SELECT date,routeid from StopDates where routeid='".$row['id']."' ORDER BY date ASC");

while($stopDates = mysql_fetch_array($driveDays)){
$orderDaysBefore = $row['lastOrderDate']; // How many days before the order must be placed.

// Change the date taken from the query to new format 
$originalDate=($stopDates['date']);
$newDate = date("d.m", strtotime($originalDate));

// Count the deadline date for the route.
$deadlineDate = strtotime ("-".$orderDaysBefore." days +12 hours", strtotime ($originalDate)) ;
$deadlineDate = Date('d.m.y G:i', $deadlineDate);


//Get current date which is then compared to the deadline date. Idea is that if currentDate is larger than deadlinedate there will be no input.
$currentDate=Date("d.m.y G:i"); 


//The line below doesnt seem to be working, i have tried mktime and time too but for some reason it just cant compare.                              
if (strtotime($currentDate) > strtotime($deadlineDate)){
// Output nothing
}
else { ?>

<p>Output stuff here</p>


<?php
}
} 
?>
```

Problem is that for some rows it hides the route and for some it doesnt. I have tried to do this with mktime and time but i cant seem to figure out what the problem is. Most of the guides i see tell to convert dates to unix timestamp format and if i understand correctly thats exactly what i am trying to do here. Im pretty sure my mistake is a simple one.

Strange thing is that for some dates it seems to work like if deadlineDate is over a month old. deadlineDate forms correctly in the `d.m.y G:i` format.

**Solved**

I skipped formatting and compared `strtotimes` 
I added:

`$currentDate2=strtotime("now");`

$deadlineDate2 = strtotime ("-".$orderDaysBefore." days +12 hours", strtotime ($originalDate)) ;

And then i compare `$currentDate2` and `$deadlineDate2`

Comment: `lastOrderDate` isn't in your query as a field to return...

Comment: You're doing waaaay too much conversion back and forth between string and timestamp formats. >。< I'm pretty sure some format conversion somewhere along the way is screwing up...

Comment: @Jared Farrish `lastOrderDate` comes from different query the value is correct.

Comment: Can you not adjust the query to perform the date comparison?

Comment: @deceze might be i will look into that.

Comment: in which formate the date stored in the database? if it's already has stamp formate than you do not need to convert it again, take the current date in stamp formate and compair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the formatting and just compare the results from `strtotime()`.